# Why does Householder tridiagonalization cost $4n^3/3$?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

In Golub, Van Loan - Matrix Computations page 459, it says

> This algorithm requires 4n^3/3 flops when symmetry is exploited in calculating the rank- 2 update.

But I don't quite understand that. How is the symmetry exploited and why is the cost 4n^3/3?

Can anyone prove it in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably easier to look at the general case of passing to Hessenberg form and then think about how effort can be saved in the symmetric case as a special case. (Unless they are doing something particularly weird.)

Comment: I like their book a lot and have two editions of it.  I'll take a look, but generally their exposition is reasonably detailed.

Comment: I think you are asking about Algorithm 8.3.1 (Householder tridiagonalization), under which the line of text you quoted appears.  Section 8.3 "The Symmetric QR Algorithm" motivates our initial reduction to tridiagonal form by $O(n^3)$ direct computation in order to reduce the work of subsequent iterative steps to $O(n^2)$ effort.  Are we on the same page, so to say?

Comment: Judging by the Table of Contents shown for the fourth edition in Google Books, I think we are looking at essentially the same material.